How can I access and remove a DOM element in Aura that is defined in Wave/CRM Analytics using React
We have a CRMA Dashboard which is rendered by a separate repo (WaveUI) and is implemented in React. It can be accessed in Analytics Tab or Analytics Studio. We can embed this dashboard within Salesforce using Lightning App Builder with the help of aura and lightning out.
We have implemented a feature to display a disclaimer message ("Confidential Information - Do Not Distribute") at the bottom of the dashboard when this dashboard is being downloaded. When a user clicks Share, a modal opens up and we take a screenshot of the dashboard to display it in that modal. When the screenshot is about to be taken, we append this disclaimer message and after the screenshot is taken and is displayed in the share modal, we then remove the disclaimer message.
We only want the disclaimer message to show up in the share modal (so the user has an idea of how the dashboard will look when it's downloaded), and when the dashboard is downloaded, NOT when normally viewing the dashboard.
This is how we add the disclaimer message to the dashboard:
const tag = document.createElement('p');
tag.classList.add('confidential-information-dashboard'); // we add some styling here
const text = document.createTextNode("Confidential Information - Do Not Distribute");
tag.appendChild(text);
rootDomNode.appendChild(tag); // rootDomNode is the root dom element of the dashboard

This is how we remove the message:
document.getElementsByClassName('confidential-information-dashboard')[0].remove();

This approach works great in Analytics Tab and Analytics Studio, however when these dashboards are embedded within Salesforce and the share button is clicked, the disclaimer message gets appended to the bottom of the dashboard (as expected) but it does not disappear when the share modal is closed.
When I try to access the element in the aura controllers using document.getElementByClassName('confidential-information-dashboard') or cmp.find('confidential-information-dashboard'), I'm unable to retrieve the object.
How do I access this object so I can remove it in Aura controllers?


Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take our quick [tour]. While the screenshot is helpful, providing any code you can share would help us identify a solution, if possible. You can [edit] your question to include the code.
